# While saving edits (or posting an answer), cancel should cancel *just the action*

Tags: feature-request, edits

(I believe all the suggested duplicates are to do with having a cancel button at all.)

I frequently post to Stack Overflow on a flaky mobile connection. It's far from unusual for me to think of an improvement to an answer while it's taking a long time to save an edit or the original post.

Unfortunately, if you click on the "cancel" link while the save is hanging, it doesn't cancel the save - it cancels the whole edit, losing whatever I've already done. This has bitten me a number of times.

I'm fine with "cancel" meaning "I don't want to make this edit" while I'm actually editing - but while the current logical action is "upload this edit to the server" I'd really like "cancel" to mean "abort the request and let me go back to editing."

Comment: This is a very good idea. This will also help some of our users in rural areas where internet is still very slow.

Comment: Is this mobile specific?

Comment: @LanceRoberts: Not the mobile experience - I'm doing this on a laptop, but using a mobile network connection.

Comment: Can't you use the back button?

Comment: @Nemo: I suspect that would lose the edit as well... which is the whole thing I'm trying to avoid.